# Обновление DataGrid без фризов

Tags: c#, wpf, асинхронность, datagrid

Есть `DataGrid`, в который выводится 100к строк запроса из базы.
Суть проблемы в том, что запрос в базу и его ожидание происходит асинхронно, как и обработка полученных данных и создание `ObservableCollection`, но есть момент, когда видимо `ObservableCollection` уведомляет `DataGrid`(реализован класс `ViewModel` с наследованным `INotifyPropyrtyChanged`) об изменении элементов и из за этого следует небольшой фриз(предположение) длительностью в секунду(примерно).
Есть ли возможность от него избавиться?

Не знаю насколько это целесообразно, но пробовал сделать метод `OnPropertyChandeg` асинхронным, но фриз никуда не делся. Также была попытка с виртуализацией, которая не увенчалась успехом.

Comment: DataGrid `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"`. И вообще ObservableCollection на время наполнения можно отключить от View, это самый быстрый способ.

Comment: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._

Comment: Спасибо! Это действительно помогло. Уточните, пожалуйста, как можно отключить `ObservableCollection` от View?

Comment: Присвоить ее в локальную переменную, а а свойство null, потом вернуть

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась предложенным ниже путем:

> DataGrid VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling". И вообще ObservableCollection на время наполнения можно отключить от View, это самый быстрый способ. - [aeopt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373567/aepot)